# onkeydown event not working on canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas, event-handling, keycode, onkeydown

I've got a canvas and an `onkeydown` event assigned to it. When **any** key is pressed, the console is supposed to log the keyCode of the key. But it's not outputting anything, not even `undefined`. Other handlers like `onclick` are working fine, but `onkeydown` is not. I've also tried using `onkeypress` and `onkeyup`, but these don't work either. Here's the full code:

```
canvas.onkeydown = function(e){
    if(e.keyCode === 37){
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        ctx.drawImage(knife,knifeX - 10, knifeY);
        knifeX -= 10;
    }
    else if(e.keyCode === 39){
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        ctx.drawImage(knife,knifeX + 10, knifeY);
        knifeX += 10;           
    }
    else if(e.keyCode === 38){
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        ctx.drawImage(knife,knifeX, knifeY + 10);
        knifeY += 10;
    }
    else if(e.keyCode === 40){
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        ctx.drawImage(knife,knifeX, knifeY - 10);
        knifeY -= 10;               
    }
    console.log(e.keyCode);     
}
```

Comment: Which browser are you testing this in?

Comment: @jsh Google Chrome, latest version.

Comment: Well keydown will fire if the focus is inside of the element, by guess is it is not focused and you should be listening to the window for the keypress.

Comment: @epascarello Thank you! Works perfectly!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead if using `canvas.onkeydown` use `window.onkeydown` otherwise you will need to focus on to the canvas for it to work.

`window.onkeydown = function() {};`

Attaching to the canvas element will only work if your focused in on that element. The window object is the whole browser.

Comment: Thanks. But shouldn't the element get focused if the user clicks on it?

Comment: @aCodingN00b Html5 canvas is one of those elements that initially has no tab setting so it will not receive focus. You can change this by simply assigning canvas a tabindex -- then it receives focus on click. ;-)