# WPF- Why keyDown function in my project does not work?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I want to add to this game: https://www.mooict.com/wpf-c-tutorial-create-a-fun-balloon-popping-game-in-visual-studio/

A function ColorKeyIsDown() that is activated when some of keys: Y,R,B,G,O are pressed.
So, if any of these keys is pressed, a specific balloon will be removed from the canvas.
I made 5 possible tags for every newBalloon that is made,
because ballonSkins integer value is from 1-5, every number declares a different background of the newBallon.

In ColorKeyIsDown() I want to identify the balloons by their tags,
But it does not work.

How can I identify each different balloon(yellow/red/blue balloon)?
Can I identify the balloon by it's background?

*In XAML:

```
 <Canvas Name="MyCanvas" Focusable="True" MouseLeftButtonDown="popBalloons" Background="White" KeyDown="ColorKeyIsDown">

    <Label Name="scoreLabel" FontSize="24" Content="Score: 0" Foreground="black" FontWeight="ExtraBold" Canvas.Top="527" />

</Canvas>
```

*In C# Code:

```
    private void ColorKeyIsDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (gameisactive)
        {
            foreach(var x in MyCanvas.Children.OfType<Rectangle>())
            {
                switch (e.Key)
                {
                    case Key.Y:
                        if ((string)x.Tag == 3.ToString()) { MyCanvas.Children.Remove(x); score++; }
                        break;
                    case Key.R:
                        if ((string)x.Tag == 1.ToString()) { MyCanvas.Children.Remove(x); score++; }
                        break;
                    case Key.B:
                        if ((string)x.Tag == 5.ToString()) { MyCanvas.Children.Remove(x); score++; }
                        break;
                    case Key.G:
                        if ((string)x.Tag == 4.ToString()) { MyCanvas.Children.Remove(x); score++; }
                        break;
                    case Key.O:
                        if ((string)x.Tag == 2.ToString()) { MyCanvas.Children.Remove(x); score++; }
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

*In C#- in gameEngine() function:

```
          // check which skin number is selected and change them to that number
            switch (balloonSkins)
            {
                case 1:
                    balloonImage.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/files/balloon1.png"));
                    break;
                case 2:
                    balloonImage.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/files/balloon2.png"));
                    break;
                case 3:
                    balloonImage.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/files/balloon3.png"));
                    break;
                case 4:
                    balloonImage.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/files/balloon4.png"));
                    break;
                case 5:
                    balloonImage.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/files/balloon5.png"));
                    break;
            }



            // make a new rectangle called new balloon
            // inside this it has a tag called bloon, height 70 pixels and width 50 pixels and balloon image as the background
            Rectangle newBalloon = new Rectangle
            {
                
                Tag = balloonSkins.ToString(),
                Height = 70,
                Width = 50,
                Fill=balloonImage
                
            };
```

Comment: What about your current code doesn't work?

Comment: At first when I pressed some of keys:Y,B,O,G,R nothing happens... So ColorKeyIsDown() doesn’t  did anything...  Someone in the comments wrote that instead of doing the KeyDown in Canvas, to do it in Window, because it’s connected to the window browser, so now it works ✌

Comment: you can answer your own question, to signal others that this is solved

Answer (score 1):

Someone wrote that instead of doing the KeyDown event in Canvas,
to do it in the window browser. solution: [onkeydown event not working on canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32936894/onkeydown-event-not-working-on-canvas)

*I changed it, and it works!